# How to write custom calibration parameters to intel Realsense D435 camera

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, realsense, camera-intrinsics

I'm working with Intelrealsense D435 and what I plan to do is to overlay an image on top of the point cloud using the [opencv_pointcloud_viewer.py](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/examples/opencv_pointcloud_viewer.py/) example in the python wrapper.

First of all, I've done calibration using checkerboard and clearly there's a difference between the values of intrinsic parameters using the calibration process and the default found using depth_profile.get_intrinsics() function.
I was wondering if there's a way to change the values of intrinsic parameters corresponding to the depth_frame in my python code. I mean I want to replace the default intrinsic values with the values I found myself so that next time I use depth_profile.get_intrinsics(), I can get the same values as the ones found during the checkerboard calibration.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I have seen https://community.intel.com/t5/Items-with-no-label/How-to-save-load-intrinsics-to-from-file-python/td-p/435336 but that doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found [intel realsense dynamic calibrator tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/645988/intel-realsense-d400-series-dynamic-calibration-tool.html) that could be used for this purpose. It's possible to define the custom XML file including the intrinsic parameters for all sensors and write them to the device.